# Do atomic operations on shared memory executing in the order of increasing the thread number?

Tags: cuda, atomic, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

Can I be sure that in this example, an atomic operation will be performed in numerical order of threads?
Or how to do it differently, excluding the use of only one thread?

```
__shared__ unsigned int cnt[MAXLEN], s[MAXLEN];

#pragma unroll
for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i+= blockDim.x) 
   p[atomicSub(cnt + s[threadIdx.x + i], 1) - 1] = threadIdx.x + i;
__syncthreads();
```

Comment: Why do you want the operations to occur in a specific order?  If they have to occur sequentially, there is no benefit to using multiple threads.  On the other hand, there may be a parallel algorithm that does not require the execution order to be restricted this way.

Comment: I want to use something like Stable Radix Sort By Key in shared memory. Or how can I do this differently?

Comment: Radix Sort is implemented with a combination of a histogram (to find the base index for each digit's subarray) and a rearrangement using Scan. Sean Baxter has a good discussion here: http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/algo.html

Comment: ArchaeaSoftware, Thanks, but I can't find there the Sort algorithm for GPU. There is only parallel algorithm for CPU. And b40c RadixSort optimized for GPU global memory, but I need for shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by numerical order of threads, you mean the thread ID number, or the order in which the threads were started, the answer is no.  Those factors play *no* reliable part in the ordering of events in threads.